# json rpc over websocket javascript client to use in qooxdoo

Tags: websocket, json-rpc, qooxdoo

I've a json rpc server with websocket transport only. 
Does any one knows about a javascript library that implement json rpc over websocket that I can use? 
Regards,

Comment: Could you give us details about the server you're using? As is this question appears to be underspecified.

Comment: It's a server that conforms to json-rpc specs [http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification]
There's tons of client implementations in all languages (java, python, nodejs) but none in pure javascript.